# Having sibling use up width of dynamic width element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This only seems to be an issue on chrome

I have two elements that are supposed to share the width of a fixed-width div. The rightmost will have some dynamically generated text and is styled using css to have a large padding so that I have some space at the left for an icon (not in the example).

I don't want the rightmost-element to either break onto a new line or to go outside the extent of the outer `div`The leftmost `input` element is supposed to use up all of the remaining space.

HTML:

```
<div id = "outer" >
  <input type="text" class="theinput">
  <span class="thetext"> hello world </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.theinput{
  width:auto;
}

.thetext{ 
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;

  padding: 0px 0px 0px 25px
}

#outer{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;

  display:inline-block;
  width:260px;
}
```

What I actually see is that once I add padding to the second element, it breaks across two lines.

[image]

I'd like to do this using only CSS and HTML, and without specifying fixed (px or %) widths for either of the sibling elements

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `display: flex` for it? Is this what you want?

```css
.theinput {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.thediv {
  color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 25px
}

#outer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  display: flex;
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <input type="text" class="theinput">
  <span class="thediv"> hello world fgfdgdfg</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work how I want. I added a whitespace:nowrap to keep the hello world from linebreaking, but it extends beyond the end of the outer div. It doesn't seem to shrink the input element.

Comment: @Gremlin can you show a pic of what you actually want?

Comment: Well, that's difficult without actually getting it working, but I've managed to that myself. You put me on the right track with `flex`, though, it just also needs `min-width:0`

Answer (score 0):

As well as @elena's answer re `flex`, it turns out that the other issue was the `min-width` property of the `input` element. Adding `min-width:0` allows it to shrink to accommodate the other element.

[image]